# NoClassDefFoundError while running kafka connect for mongodb in standalone mode

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium, mongodb-kafka-connector

I am trying to set up debezium connector with MongoDB in a standalone mode on my local machine by following [this](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/connectors/mongodb.html#setting-up-mongodb).

I have set up a replica set of MongoDB with 3 nodes, 1 master 2 replica (host = localhost, port = 27017, 27018, 27019) . I have started kafka and zookeper on the local machine as a [quickstart guide](https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart).

After this, I downloaded the MongoDB connector plugin jar from [here](https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/artifact/maven/redirect?r=snapshots&g=io.debezium&a=debezium-connector-mongodb&v=LATEST&c=plugin&e=tar.gz).

Set plugin.path variable to mongodb plugin jars as :

```
plugin.path=dbz_connector_mongodb_jar_path,KAFKA_HOME/libs
```

created connector config for standalone mode.

KAFKA_HOME/config/my_mongo_connector.properties :

```
{
  "name": "my-mongo-connector", 
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mongodb.MongoDbConnector", 
    "mongodb.hosts": "rc0/127.0.0.1:27017", 
    "mongodb.name": "myMongoConnceter", 
    "collection.include.list": "dbname.collectionName" 
  }
}
```

Now when I run kafka connect with below command :

```
cd KAFKA_HOME    
bin/connect-standalone.sh config/connect-standalone.properties config/my_mongo_connector.properties
```

I see below error :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/MongoException
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:3137)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3342)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:556)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.versionFor(DelegatingClassLoader.java:392)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.getPluginDesc(DelegatingClassLoader.java:362)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.scanPluginPath(DelegatingClassLoader.java:334)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.scanUrlsAndAddPlugins(DelegatingClassLoader.java:268)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.registerPlugin(DelegatingClassLoader.java:260)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.initPluginLoader(DelegatingClassLoader.java:229)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.initLoaders(DelegatingClassLoader.java:206)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.Plugins.<init>(Plugins.java:61)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone.main(ConnectStandalone.java:78)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mongodb.MongoException
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 13 more
```

Then I added `mongo-java-driver-3.12.10.jar` file to the kafka connect plugins folder which has this class `com.mongodb.MongoException` . But still, I face the same error.

I have also found that this jar is loading while running kafka connect command :

```
INFO Loading plugin from: debezium-connector-mongodb_path/mongo-java-driver-3.12.10.jar (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:246)
INFO Registered loader: PluginClassLoader{pluginLocation=file:debezium-connector-mongodb_path/mongo-java-driver-3.12.10.jar} (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:269)
```

EDIT :

My problem of NoClassDefFoundError was solved by correcting plugin.path.

Earlier it was `/opt/debezium-connector-mongodb`  and I changed it to `/opt` , as suggested in the comment.

My another mistake : I was taking connector propeties file in json format, so changed it into properties file format :

```
name:my-mongo-connector
connector.class:io.debezium.connector.mongodb.MongoDbConnector
mongodb.hosts=rc0/127.0.0.1:27017
mongodb.name=myMongoConnector
collection.include.list=dbname.collectionName
topic.creation.default.replication.factor=1
topic.creation.default.partitions=2
mongodb.members.auto.discover=false
```

Now kafka connect started but on insertion of new entry in mongo collection, kafka topic is not creating.

So now the problem is unable to create kafka topic even after data insertion in DB.

Comment: You need to point the plugin path to the **parent folder** of the extracted folder with all the JARs

Comment: This worked for me. But I am facing another problem : Connector config ..... contains no connector type

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the new error

Comment: RE: topic creation, please read https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/configuration/topic-auto-create-config.html